# Setting number on a button image

Tags: c#, css

I am working with C# and CSS to render an iPhone notification-type button. I have a field in a SQL Server database to get outstanding deliveries for a product. If there are more than 1 outstanding deliveries, then I want this number to appear in a blob button which I have created here:

[image]

So, if there are 2 outstanding deliveries, then I want the '2' to appear inside the red blob. How can I bind this data coming from the database into a background image (z-index in CSS can only be used with images, so I am confused as to how to use them)? Thank you for any guidance provided.

Comment: How are you talking to your db? Are you using MVC?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework with an simple ASP.NET Web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by superimposing a label on a button using the technique: [Overlap Button with a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961747/overlap-button-with-a-label)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MVC:

1. Call an action that gets the value from the db (from jQuery)
2. Use jQuery to set the value in your CSS/HTML

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Can you give me an example?

Comment: After you show me what you have tried (update your question). :)