# Overlap Button with a label

Tags: html, css, overlap

I was wondering if anyone knows how you can overlap a button with a label in HTML.

For example:

[image: picture]

Is this easily done with css? I have tried absolute positioning to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/y9dfX/9/

I created a container `div` with `position:relative` which contains the button and label. Then i just set the label with `position:absolute` and added top and left positions. Only drawback is that you have to set the positions manually.

Comment: thanks for the response. do you know of a way where you dont have to set the positions manually and it goes to the bottom right?

Comment: Ok I think I have managed to do so: http://jsfiddle.net/Pawcu/y9dfX/11/ All i did was set the container div to be the width of the button by floating it left and then set a bottom and right position instead of top and left of 5px each. Hope this helps even more :)